# How to add mouse over zoom in only for y axis using d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming, svgpanzoom

I have draw a chart like [brush and zoom](https://blockbuilder.org/AlainRo/542b063a12524a2f17d1005c1d4beb6e)
and I want to add another zoom event for y axis(the present is only zoom in x axis) when the mouse is on the y axis and zoom in

and I add some code like this:

```
var zoomY = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
    .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .on("zoom", zoomedY);

 function zoomedY(){
   focus.select(".axis--y")
     .call(yAxis.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleY(y)));
  //
  y.domain(d3.event.transform.rescaleY(y).domain());

 };

focus.select(".axis--y").call(zoomY);
```

And the problem if I remove the `d3.event.transform.rescaleY(yChart).domain()` ,the y axis will change when mouse on and zoom in/out, but the graph will not change. After I add this, is ok when zoom in but it can not zoom back(just stuck and the page scroll down).
How can I fix this problem or is there a better solution to do this?

Comment: add a `rect` behind your y-axis and attach the zoom/mouse events to this, this `rect` will not change when you `zoom` the y-axis

Comment: do you mean `.append("g").append("rect")` , I have tried this , but still has the same problem ,cannot zoom back.

Comment: do you want a zoom or a brush on the y-axis

Comment: I found the problem. I should not change the y domain, but I should update the line function like  `d3.line()
           .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
            .x(function (d) {
                return new_xScale(d.x);
            })
            .y(function (d) {
                return new_yScale(d.y);
            });`  in [link](https://bl.ocks.org/NGuernse/35c77cbbca4b7f06a75afcd16e4e19aa)  thank you.

Comment: But I have a new little problem , when zoom in the y axis ,the page will scroll at the same time